# How to see what filter was applied to a gmail message?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have some filters setup in Gmail to send emails that match certain criteria to certain folders.

To problem is some of these do not seem to be work correctly and i wonder if its due to the emails matching multiple criteria.

Is it possible to see what filters where applied to a message, so that i can work out where the conflicting filters are ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot however you can test your filters individually to see if they work.

FYI: Applying a label to an email using one filter should not affect another filter that applies a different label to that same email. This is because of the way Gmail processes filters

Your issue is likely an issue with that specific filter.